# Consistency of fields between institutions

Tags: yodlee

When using API calls such as `https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getItemSummaries` to get item summaries, is there any guarantee of consistency of fields between different institutions for the same `acctType`?

As an example, if you have a `savings` account (i.e. `acctType` is `savings`) with Westpac (Australian Institution) which has a `currentBalance` with amount 368.00 and currency AUD, will the same field `currentBalance` exist for a `savings` `acctType` for ANZ (another Australian institution), with the exact same fields. Is there a comprehensive list which details which fields differ across `acctType` (should they differ at all)?

Furthermore, is there an enumeration of the possible `acctType` that you can get when querying customer data from an institution

Also is there documentation that describes what field names mean, as an example there is `acctType` and `localizedAcctType`, what is the difference between the two?

Finally is there a list of institutions separated by countries (in my case, Australia) that we can use by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yodlee has data model designed as per different types of banking products like bank accounts, credit card accounts, loan accounts, investment accounts and so on. In Yodlee's terminology all these different products are called as containers. Now each container has their own set of fields which are relevent to any type of accounts under that category. Account_types are also a field under each container.
Now savings/Checking accounts comes under bank container and will have same set of fields across all financial institutions and will not vary until and unless the financial institution does not have any of those fields present at their website.

You can find the list of accountTypes from this link

https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Yodlee_Account_Types

For complete look at the Yodlee data model you can check 
https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model

As of now we don't have any documentation which provides the meaning of each an every fields. You can actually ignore the localizedAcctType field and use the value from acctType field. Similarly you can ignore any such fields for different responses.

There is no such list available but there are APIs to get list of institutions by geographic region.